# Java for loop making asterisk matrix

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix, nested, asterisk

I've currently trying to make this form with a for loop in Java:

```
**********
 ********* 
  ******** 
   ******* 
    ****** 
     ***** 
      **** 
       ***
        **
         *
```

My code looks like this:

```
        for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
        for (int star = 10; star >= 1; star--) {
            if (star >= row) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I can't seem to figure out to make the whitespace go before the stars. I've tried switching the loop conditions, but it just gives me the same result.
There's something about these for-loops i'm not getting. Can someone point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Try `if (star < row) {`.

Comment: Hint: such things are really perfect for using the debugger. And even better: you can run them on paper. Just take a pen, and execute your code manually. I am sure it wont take you more than 5 minutes of doing that before you figure your problem.

Comment: What's in a name? `for int column P= 1` instead of `star = 10` would have been less mind boggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried to analyze your code and what I found is

**Your Mistake:**

Here we see that the desired output and your output becomes different from output line number 2 and the reason I found is the `if` condition that is `star >= row` so lets iterate the loop of star for the `row` value `2`:

```
if(star >= row) //when star = 10 - condition true. * will be the output

if(star >= row) //when star = 9 - condition true. * will be the output

if(star >= row) //when star = 8 - condition true. * will be the output
```

so `*` will be the output untill the `star>=row` returns false which will be `star = 1` scenario for this iteration.
Similarly for `row = 3` the condition will be true unless the `star` value becomes `<=2`. So the problem is that you are printing `*` in the start and the condition for  comes after printing the `*`.

**Possible Solution:**

Basically you need to print  in the start, not in the end. So with the same condition you may need to reverse the iteration method for the columns in order to reverse your print order. if you change the order of your loop you can do the job. Lets iterate the loop for the `row` value of `2`:

```
if(star >= row) //when star = 1 - condition false. ` ` will be the output

if(star >= row) //when star = 2 - condition true. * will be the output

if(star >= row) //when star = 8 - condition true. * will be the output
```

so in this case the  will be printed first and the `*` will be printed later.

**Updated Code:**

I have updated your code. Have a look at the `inner for loop`.

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++)
{
    for (int star = 1; star <= 10; star++)
    {
        if (star >= row)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner loop to a standard 1 to 10 loop.

```
  for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
    for (int star = 1; star <= 10; star++) {
        if (star >= row) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int size = 10;
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int i = size - row; i > 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first job is to step away from the keyboard and think through the problem. It turns out that the condition for a star is "current row >= current column".

Implement that using

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 10; ++row){
    for (int col = 1; col <= 10; ++col){
        System.out.print( row >= col ? "*" : " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){

         for(int j = 0 ; j < 10  ; j++){

             if(j >= i){
                System.out.print("*"); 
             }else{
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
         }
            System.out.println("");

     }
```